# Undelete NTFS Files to Same Location

Tags: backup, data-recovery, file-recovery

My backup utility deleted about 200 GB of data accidentally from my backup drive. I still have the data on my main drive but it will take too much time if I copy and paste it again.

Is there a way to undelete the deleted files (restore the entries to the MFT again)?

I have tried Recuva, Glary Undelete, Active@ UNERASER, etc. but none of them restore the deleted files entries back to the MFT, they can only copy the deleted files to another location.

Answer (score -1):

You may wanna check out a program called "Advanced System Care Pro" If you don't know about it, it's a really good overall program for cleaning/repairing/maintaining/optimizing you computer... One of it's feature's is a "tool box" which is a collection of different program's for all sorts of things, one of them being "Undelete"... I don't know much about that particular tool, but it says it's for recovering files that have been cleared out of you recycle bin... It's not much but a suggestion, but I hope it helps...